# xsl:message terminate attribute defined by variable (setup like)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Define xsl variable to for `terminate` attribute of `<xsl:message>` does not work:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="TERMINATE_ON_ERROR" select="'no'" />

<xsl:message terminate="$TERMINATE_ON_ERROR">
    <xsl:text>foo</xsl:text>
</xsl:message>
<!-- ... -->
<xsl:message terminate="$TERMINATE_ON_ERROR">
    <xsl:text>bar</xsl:text>
</xsl:message>
```

This forces me to use `terminate="no"` for all cases:

```xml
<xsl:message terminate="no">
    <xsl:text>foo</xsl:text>
</xsl:message>
<!-- ... -->
<xsl:message terminate="no">
    <xsl:text>bar</xsl:text>
</xsl:message>
```

and then replace all of them if I change my mind instead of changing just single variable.

I prefer solution for XSLT 1.0 (using `xsltproc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#message) and 3 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-message) the `terminate` attribute allows an attribute value template (e.g. `terminate="{$TERMINATE_ON_ERROR}"`) but XSLT 1 https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#message doesn't seem to allow it.

So the main XSLT like approach in that case of XSLT 1 would be to write one stylesheet to create a second stylesheet, for that you have to use `xsl:namespace-alias`, as shown in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Creating-Elements-and-Attributes.

Comment: Simpler solution for XSLT 1.0 is to have a named template that takes a parameter, and uses xsl:choose to decide based on the parameter whether to call `xsl:message terminate="yes"` or `xsl:message terminate="no"`. Note also that for XSLT 2.0 the run-time value of the AVT has to be yes/no, for 3.0 it also accepts true/false.

Comment: Martin, actually I verified that AVTs do work in the @terminate attribute -- see my answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, interesting, XslCompiledTransform and MSXML 6 reject that code. xsltproc, which the original poster asked about, reacts strange, outputting `xsl:message : terminate expecting 'yes' or 'no'` and `XXX` three times to finally state: `no result for name-of-input-file`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen So, xsltproc actually executes xsl:message correctly, despite the nagging :)  The "no result" is expected as this particular transformation doesn't have any  output -- only the side effects from xsl:message

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, as for xsltproc, no, not really, if I change the variable or parameter to have the value `yes` I continue to get those three complaints `xsl:message : terminate expecting 'yes' or 'no'` together with the three `XXX`s.

Comment: @MartinHonnen So, they made a "shortcut" -- anything that is not the literal 'yes' is treated like the literal 'no' -- this is a bug, but I doubt anyone will be willing to update Saxon 6 at this time...